# htaccess redirect from time to time

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect my page, after closing at night at 19.00 and then it should stop again, in the morning 06:00

I did try sevel codes, from excambles out there.
But here is my last try, but nothing happens.
I did change the time, to test it.

```
ReWriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >=12
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <18
RewriteRule ^ /test.html [R,L]
```

it worked if I toke away the =

```
ReWriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >13
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <15
RewriteRule !^test\.html$ /test.html [R,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to redirect this between 7 PM and 6 AM, you may use:

```
ReWriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >=19
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <=6
RewriteRule !^test\.html$ /test.html [R,NC,L]
```

`!^test\.html$` is negative condition to stop redirect loop.

Comment: That's fine, even Apache uses 24 hr numbers. 7 PM is 19 hrs and 6 AM is 06 hrs above.

Comment: ok I did change the time now, for testing

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >=11
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <=15
RewriteRule !^test\.html$ /test.html [R,NC,L]

it dos not work

Comment: I have tested this rule on my Apache and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I suggest you comment out one of the `RewriteCond` and test according to local time there, so .may be just one condition: `RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >=10`

Comment: it worked when I toke the = away. Thanks for helping :)